# Economics Blog: News, book reviews, etc

Tags: discussion

If I remember correctly I think Math.SE has a blog where the moderators of the community, every once in a while post something. I think a blog for our economics community would have immense value. The moderators, or users of high enough reputation could comment on recent news/events, review some literature/bibliography that shows up, talk about an interesting perspective on to interpret a model, etc. I think the possibilities are endless. In my opinion, it will all depend on the user ability to allocate some of his time for these tasks...

What do you think?